# Setting up mousedown functions using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a whole bunch of similar list items that I want to attach `mousedown()` functions to.  So what I would like to do is replace this:

```
$('#controls li[id=d1]').mousedown(function(){
    console.log('d1');
});
$('#controls li[id=d2]').mousedown(function(){
    console.log('d2');
});
```

with this:

```
var loopvar;
for (loopvar = 1; loopvar <= 2; loopvar++) {
    $('#controls li[id=d' + loopvar + ']').mousedown(function(){
        console.log('d' + loopvar);
    });
}
```

(This is a simplified example - I actually have lots of `li`'s to handle.)
But when I click on an `li`, I always get `d3` on the console.  The value of `loopvar` is 3 when the loop ends, so it looks like that is what is happening.  So how can I attach the functions using a loop?

Comment: You've just meet a thing called closure. One of the most powerful yet dangerous (if you don't know how to work with it) features of JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript Closures  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: In this case you can just use console.log(this.id)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I have decades of C/C++ experience and _weeks_ of JavaScript experience!  So closure is a new concept for me.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should never ever do that.
2. you should use classes instead of ids.

To use IDs anyway, try :

```
$('#controls li[id^="d"]').mousedown(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

To use a loop, you have to use a closure to pass the var, however it's bad to assign callbacks like this, use the method above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    (function(loopvar) {
        $('#controls li[id=d' + loopvar + ']').mousedown(function(){
            console.log('d' + loopvar);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of the jquery selector and using a class instead of id's. Good stuff. I'm a C programmer, so I immediately jump to a `for()` loop for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Welcome to the javascript world, it's a wonderful world once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
var loopvar;
for (loopvar = 1; loopvar <= 3; loopvar++) {
    $('#controls li[id=d' + loopvar + ']').mousedown((function(loopvar){
        return function(e){
            console.log(e);
           console.log('d' + loopvar);
        }
    })(loopvar)); //You create a closure locking in the loop iteration variable
}
```

But ideal scenario you would just need to bind an event to the a selector either usind a common class name or using an id starts with selector.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5skeF/)**

With startswith selector:

```
$('#controls li[id^=d]').mousedown(function(e){
        console.log(this.id); //here this represents the element you clicked on.
    }
);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6dm3/)**

*Also do remember that id starts with selector is an attribute selector and would be slower compared to a class selector*

Answer (score 0):

If the example you've written is very similar to your actual code, I'd solve it like this:

```
$('#controls').find('li[id]').mousedown(function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
    // If you want to use jQuery...
    // console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Note that `$('#controls').find('li[id]')` is slightly faster than `$('#controls li[id]')`